# Script processes stop without error when trying to call predict() from nlp model while using multiprocessing

Tags: python, nlp, multiprocessing, pickle

I had a working python pipeline which i wanted to speed up by using the multiprocessing library. Inside my pipeline i use the nlp model "flair". With multiprocessing the processes die in the background without an error and Pycharm still thinks the script is running when i use the `predict()` function from "flair".

For the multiprocessing i used the following guide from: https://everydayimlearning.blogspot.com/2013/03/multiprocessing-with-python.html

Here is a minimal, reproducable example:

```
import multiprocessing
from flair.models import SequenceTagger # pip install flair
from flair.data import Sentence

class TestClass:
    tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-german")
    print("tagger loaded")
    def testFunction(self):
        print("f started")
        s = Sentence("thats a text")
        self.tagger.predict(s) # script gets stuck here <-----------
        print("predicted")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def parallel_execution(tasks, q):
        for task in tasks:
            try:
               instance = TestClass()
               instance.testFunction()
            except Exception as error:
                raise
        q.put("done")

    task = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    procs = []
    MULTI_CORES = 4

    for i in range(0, MULTI_CORES):
        lst = [task [j] for j in range(0, len(task)) if j % MULTI_CORES == i]

        if len(lst) > 0:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=parallel_execution, args=([lst, q]))
            p.start()
            procs += [p]
    all_results = []
    for i in range(0, len(procs)):
        all_results.append(q.get())
```

Without the multiprocessing the script predicts just fine:

```
from flair.models import SequenceTagger # pip install flair
from flair.data import Sentence

class TestClass:
    tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-german")
    print("tagger loaded")
    def testFunction(self):
        print("f started")
        s = Sentence("thats a text")
        self.tagger.predict(s) # script gets stuck here <----------------
        print("predicted")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def parallel_execution(tasks):
        for task in tasks:
            try:
               instance = TestClass()
               instance.testFunction()
            except Exception as error:
                raise

    task = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    parallel_execution(task)
```

Comment: You have not posted a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it's difficult (at least for me) to say where the problem is. As an aside, you have used as your guide to code this a fairly poor example. And it doesn't relieve you from actually learning multiprocessing. There are things in your code that you have copied by rote that don't make any sense in your code, such as writing "done" to  a Queue just so the main process knows that the subprocess has finished. Using a multiprocessing pool makes the program simpler and clearer.

Comment: @Booboo thank you for your feedback, i rephrased the whole question and added code samples to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I installed **flair** (it's quite a bundle of modules that come with it) and *attempted* a simple test of instantiating a `TestClass` instance in my main process and calling `testFunction` and then creating a single `multiprocessing.Process` instance with `insance.testFunction` as the target and it nearly crashed my computer (it probably was running out of memory) so I killed the command prompt (I am running Windows) before it had a chance to finish (it it ever would have finished). It did get far enough along for **flair** to print out a load message.

But one of us or both us may be confused. You seem to be running the same exact function repeatedly with the same exact arguments. This is what has me confused. You do realize that each process that you create will be executing the statement `tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-german")`, right? And since each process is starting off with the same initialized data and does not appear to be saving any state, how could anything be getting learned by repeated identical calls? Perhaps this just shows my lack of understanding.

So I can only attribute my getting stuck to a lack of resources. Anyway, this is how I would recode your program using a multiprocessing pool. I have tried to add comments to make it clearer. But there is no substitute for reading the documentation for the [`multiprocessing.pool.Pool` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#multiprocessing.pool.Pool).

```py
import multiprocessing
from flair.models import SequenceTagger # pip install flair
from flair.data import Sentence


class TestClass:
    tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-german")
    print("tagger loaded")

    def testFunction(self):
        print("f started")
        s = Sentence("thats a text")
        self.tagger.predict(s) # script gets stuck here <-----------
        print("predicted")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MULTI_CORES = 4
    # Create a pool with MULTI_CORES processes:
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MULTI_CORES)
    # We seem to be creating 8 identical tasks, but why?
    results = []
    for _ in range(8):
        test_class = TestClass()
        results.append(pool.apply_async(test_class.testFunction))
    # Wait for each submitted task to complete:
    # If you testFunction returns a value you are interested in
    # (currently it just returns None) or you want to see if it raised
    # an exception, then execute the following loop. Otherwise,
    # you can just proceed to the close and join method calls.
    TEST_RESULTS = True
    if TEST_RESULTS:
        for result in results:
            try:
                return_value = result.get() # None for now
            except Exception as e:
                print('Exception:', e)
    # The following two statements will also wait for all submitted
    # tasks to complete and should be executed in any case.
    # If you are not interested in testing
    # the results, then you do not need to save the
    # return values from calling apply_async:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

You can also

Comment: Thank you for trying and providing a sample with pool. As you pointed out there is no point in the identical tasks. The issue i wanted to display is the script dying inside the "predict()" function while multiprocessing and it persists in your code sample as well for me. The console prints: "2022-01-25 08:55:57,862 loading file /home/ec2-user/.flair/models/ner-german/a125be40445295f7e94.... || tagger loaded || f started" and the process is killed in the background without an error. You can test it with MULTI_CORES = 1 to reduce the ram load on your machine...it still crashes for me.